Prioritize numeric result in CTE when more than one row per date
I am working with time recording data and I have a problem when people have registered more than one thing in a day.
An example of the data:



Date
Reason
Hours




2024-05-20
NULL
NULL


2024-05-21
90011
1.4


2024-05-22
Work
1


2024-05-22
90011
0,4


2024-05-23
Work
0,9



Where 2024-05-20 have NULL values because it is weekend and no records are expected there.
My problems is with 2024-05-22 where there more than 1 records - the person have worked and been ill.
When there is more than one row per date I only want the numeric one – so in this case I would like the following results:



Date
Reason
Hours




2024-05-20
NULL
NULL


2024-05-21
90011
1.4


2024-05-22
90011
0,4


2024-05-23
Work
0,9



Anyone that have a solution so I can "clean" my data of these instances?

Please post your full CREATE TABLE statements. Do your tables not have PKs defined?
